# Review Link in Question/Answers itself

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, edits, review

Can we get a Review Question, and Review Answer link directly on questions/answers that haven't previously been reviewed?

A lot of times I find myself browsing newest questions, or unanswered questions, and they're in poor shape and most likely not reviewed yet; so I end up editing them, but not getting the review "credit" and it's still not marked as reviewed either.

Comment: Is there a "review" credit? I wasn't aware of that. *[predicts new wave of meta posts, reminiscent of the flag weight wars]*

Comment: I mean your actual review statistics where you can keep track of how many you've edited, and reviewed, I believe the same portion that's used for badges.

Comment: Part of the motivation for such badges is to get users to spend a small amount of time in the `/review` queue reviewing posts that are identified as needing review.

Comment: So give it to only people who already have at least one review badge, meaning they already actively review, and only keep it to questions already in need of review. All I was trying to say was it'll save me time sometimes, as well as others, who won't have to re-review something I just reviewed/edited as I was answering/reading questions.

Comment: It might be a bad idea, but it would be very easy to make a user script to add this.

Comment: This is available to moderators now, to allow them to "review the reviewers" when necessary. I tend to agree with dmckee though, it would just be a distraction for most viewers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sympathetic to Robert's comment about pushing users to spend some time browsing the `/review` pages, but I find myself delaying working on question from users with less than 10 rep until after I've poked round `/review` to see if the question I've found shows up there.

The result is these questions are getting my comments/answers/votes/flags *later* than they would otherwise.

In some sense this seems to work *against* the desired for fast response to questions and problems.

Comment: aye, precisely the reason I was looking for it. I also agree with Robert though, so like I said, maybe limiting it to just the folks who already have a silver or gold review badge would be fine.